# Excel - Negative numbers to zero

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a cell with a negative number, but I want to put 0 instead of negative number. How can I make this? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you write `=MAX(0;your formula)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
=IF(A1<0,0,A1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! :)